# How to fix "TypeError: this.props is undefined" in React

Tags: reactjs

I was following tutorial on React on youtube but since it is a little outdated I am getting error.

I googled and I found some people were able to solve it by adding constructor and I have tried to add constructor to code (which is not done in tutorial) but it still gives same error.

This is App class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/Main';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    types: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Bug",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Task",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Issue",
        chosen: false
      },
    ],

    states: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "New",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "In progress",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Done",
        chosen: false
      },
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Main main={this.state.main} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return this.props.main.map((mai) => (
            <h3>{mai.title}</h3>
        ));
    }
}

export default Main;
```

I am getting error "TypeError: this.props.main is undefined"

Comment: Don't pass undefined to it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for such an explicit reply with question mark at the end. I am totally new to react and got little confused. Now I see it was a simple mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error: `"TypeError: this.props.main is undefined"`.
It means that you don't have a 'main' property inside props object.
But you do pass it into the "main" property in your jsx, but the question is **what** are you passing:

`<Main main={this.state.main} />` => you are trying to pass the 'main' property of the state object, but it does not exists. You only have 'types' and 'states' properties.

So, you have 2 options:

1. renaming one of those to 'main' and leave code as it is.
2. pass one of the other state properties, e.g `<Main main={this.state.states} />`.

Answer (score 1):

You pass on your `<Main />` component `this.state.main` which is **undefined**. You may meant to pass `this.state.states` or `this.state.types`?

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code as working one, please see and provide feedback,

Suggestion is to use only class component when needed go for stateless component for better performance.

```
 Main = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (props && props.map((mai, index) => (
      <><h3 key={index}>{mai.title}</h3></>)
  ));
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.Main(this.state.states)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Updated code below,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Component } from 'react'; 

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    types: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Bug",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Task",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Issue",
        chosen: false
      },
    ],

    states: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "New",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "In progress",
        chosen: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Done",
        chosen: false
      },
    ]
  }
  Main = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (props && props.map((mai, index) => (
      <><h3 key={index}>{mai.title}</h3></>)
  ));
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.Main(this.state.states)}
      </div>
    );
  }
} 
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```